# Choosing ngrok subscription for using Google Calendar API

Tags: ssl, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, ngrok

I want to be able to expose my local machine address to the internet to be able to work with:

- Google OAuth2 flow;
- Receiving Push-Notifications for changes in my calendars/events;

So that, I need some tool that will expose my local machine URLs to the Internet so Google will be able to use this web hooks.

I found that ngrok with basic(5$) subscription works for me. Free versions doesn't work since I need SSL as it's required by [google](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push):

> This is your Webhook callback URL, and it must use HTTPS. Note that
>   the Google Calendar API will be able to send notifications to this
>   HTTPS address only if there is a valid SSL certificate installed on
>   your web server. Invalid certificates include: •  Self-signed
>   certificates. •   Certificates signed by an untrusted source.
>   • Certificates that have been revoked. •  Certificates that have a
>   subject that doesn't match the target hostname.

The question is whether there is something else I haven't taken into account that will force me to buy more expensive type of subscription? Maybe some specific requirenments from Google that basic subscription can't work with.

Comment: Ngrok ssl (with no subscription) is a wildcard one and is supposed to work for this situation.

Comment: You need a static URL address. Cause you subscribe on push-notifications and you want to keep getting them after you restart your computer or just ngrok. That's why basic subscription helped us here.

Answer (score 1):

Basic $5 subscription works perfectly. It fits all Google's requirements + it provides static URLs that make it possible to receive PUSH notifications even when you restart your ngrok or computer.

Comment: From then on, have appeared any alternative? google needs to verify you are the owner on domain...

Comment: It's only for test purposes. You can change your domain multiple times in ngrok and work with a single google project for 100 sign up. If you want to verify it on prod though, you will need a dedicated domain associated with your app permanently.